# May I use a root user to expose the python bottle application to the Internet?

Tags: python, linux, security, web-applications, bottle

I made a WEB application using Bottle and want to publish it. I decided to use `paste` for the web server because [official document](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#switching-the-server-backend) said it's the easiest way.

In order to let the web server process listen on the port 80, the process must be launched by the root user. I'm not a security expert and can not judge that it's safe to use the root user for launching an application that is exposed to the internet directly.

Shall I avoid using root user in such a situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

Do not run your web server as `root`.

> Shall I avoid using root user in such a situation?

Yes, avoid running as `root`.

> In order to let the web server process listen on the port 80

Your web server does not need to listen on port 80. One common way to structure this is to put a proxy (like a load balancer) in front of your web server. Your server listens on a non-privileged port (e.g. 8000); the load balancer (which is listening on port 80) forwards all requests to your server.

The accepted answer (which does not actually answer your question) merely mentions `chroot`, but I suggest that you not worry about that. Running as a non-privileged user is a much more important safeguard than using `chroot`. I would consider `chroot` to be secondary to your initial, quite legitimate, concerns over running as `root`.

Comment: Thank you. Let me ask one more question. To my understanding, the proxy should be launched by root (because it should listen on port 80). What's the difference between launching web server and proxy as root ?

Comment: You're welcome! Good question. A proxy is not running your code; it's running purpose-built, hardened code that does only one thing. Your web server, on the other hand, can do anything it wants, which includes inadvertently creating security holes.

Answer (score -1):

It is recommended to create an chrooted environment with an restricted user.

Over here you can find a howto on how to create a chrooted environment [www.howtogeek.com/441534/how-to-use-the-chroot-command-on-linux/amp/](http://www.howtogeek.com/441534/how-to-use-the-chroot-command-on-linux/amp/)